# Directional light view frustum stabilisation

Tags: graphics, shadows, shadow-mapping, bounding-boxes, frustum

Calculating directional light view frustum based on scene objects(bounding frustum) results in noticeable scene jittering on camera movement in CSM and non-CSM rendering code paths. What are the techniques to reduce or eliminate these jittering artifacts?